# ¿$\sqrt{6}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3+\sqrt{3}})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, radicals

I am trying to prove rigorously that $\sqrt{6}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3+\sqrt{3}})$ or that $\sqrt{6}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3+\sqrt{3}})$.
Intuitively, I would say that the first option is the correct one, but I do not know how to justify this in a rigorous way.

Any ideas as to how to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are very likely several way to address this problem, but if you provide no information at all about what your tried yourself or what you know, it is difficult for people to actually answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $\alpha=\sqrt{-3+\sqrt{3}}$ we see that $\alpha$ is a root of $(X^2+3)^2-3$. This polynomial is irreducible by Eisenstein. Hence $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is of degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Suppose now that $\sqrt{6}\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Since $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ (look at $\alpha^2$) we would have that $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. That is we would have that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. But it is easy to see that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is already of degree $4$ over the rationals, and so we would have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})= \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

So suppose that we have rationals $a,b,c,d$ such that $(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6})^2=-3+\sqrt{3}$. Squaring out we see that we would have that $a^2+2b^2+3c^2+6d^2=-3$, a contradiction.

Hence $\sqrt{6}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

(And the Galois group of the splitting field is the dihedral group of order $8$.)